# How to dismiss UISheetPresentationController that is visible when app becomes sceneWillResignActive or sceneDidEnterBackground

Tags: swift, uisheetpresentationcontroller

I'm presenting a `UISheetPresentationController` as the following when a user taps on a gear icon.

```
@IBAction func settings(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SettingsViewController")
    
    if let presentationController = viewController.presentationController as? UISheetPresentationController {
   
        presentationController.detents = [.medium(),.large()]
     
        self.present(viewController, animated: true)
        
    }
}//settings
```

However I'm also checking to ensure the Notifications are enabled / disabled.  If Notifications has been disabled, I popup and `UIAlertController` when the app enters the foreground in `sceneDidBecomeActive`

However if the SettingsViewController was visible on the screen after the app becomes active, I get the following error:

```
Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x145008200> on <UINavigationController: 0x14301a200> (from <xxx.ViewController: 0x14280d8a0>) which is already presenting <xxx.SettingsViewController: 0x142d17460>.
```

How can I dismiss the UISheetPresentationController when the app becomes `sceneWillResignActive` or `sceneDidEnterBackground`